# How to shift 2D array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hi this is my 2D array format. I want to remove 1st inside array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => section-open
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => section-close
                )

        )

)
```

I want to remove all inside array and return it like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => section-open
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => section-close
        )

)
```

I tried `array_shift` function it's not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you probably want a real 2d shift I made a function which does that, removing the first level in the array, but keeping ALL the items in the second level.

Here is a working example:

http://codepad.org/H7iaTI1E

And the function:

```
/**
 * Removes first level in an array, returning the 2nd level elements as an array
 * @param array Array to process
 * @return 2nd level items from the given array
 */
function array2dshift(array $array) {
    $res = array();

    foreach($array as $lvl1) {
        foreach($lvl1 as $item) {
            $res[] = $item;
        }
    }

    return $res;
}
```

Comment: @sg3s This is not a recursive function.

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: This was based on the example the user gave, but he expected it to work for arrays with more than one element.

`array_shift()` removes the first element of an array, but that's not what you want.

You have to build something yourself.

Something like:

```
$result = array();
foreach($my_array as $element)
{
    $result[]=$element[0];
}
```

Comment: @Ikke that code will blow up if there is ever more than one item in the second level.

Comment: This was based on the example @mifas gave.